# Grayscale to Binary?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, binary, grayscale

I'm trying to convert a grayscale image to a binary. The code I have converts a bitmap to grayscale, but I'm at loss as to how to make that image into a binary. Here is the code I currently have. PLEASE HELP ME!!! Thanks!

```
package com.example.vanderbilt;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Canvas;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrix;
import android.graphics.ColorMatrixColorFilter;
import android.graphics.Paint;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import org.opencv.android.Utils;
import org.opencv.core.Mat;
import org.opencv.imgproc.Imgproc;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
```

public class Binary extends Activity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.binary);
    ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.ivBinary);

    /*
     * Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
     * R.drawable.sample4); Bitmap bmpGray = toGrayscale(bmp);
     * img.setImageBitmap(bmpGray);
     */

    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.sample4);
    Mat imgToProcess = Utils.bitmapToMat(bmp);

    for (int i = 0; i < imgToProcess.height(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < imgToProcess.width(); j++) {
            double y = 0.3 * imgToProcess.get(i, j)[0] + 0.59
                    * imgToProcess.get(i, j)[1] + 0.11
                    * imgToProcess.get(i, j)[2];
            imgToProcess.put(i, j, new double[] { y, y, y, 255 });
        }
    }

    int widthM, heightM, rowsM, colsM;
    colsM = imgToProcess.cols();
    rowsM = imgToProcess.rows();
    heightM = imgToProcess.height();
    widthM = imgToProcess.width();

    Bitmap bmpOut = Bitmap.createBitmap(imgToProcess.cols(),
            imgToProcess.rows(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    Utils.matToBitmap(imgToProcess, bmpOut);
    img.setImageBitmap(bmpOut);

}

    public Bitmap toGrayscale(Bitmap bmpOriginal) {
    int width, height;
    height = bmpOriginal.getHeight();
    width = bmpOriginal.getWidth();

    Bitmap bmpGrayscale = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
            Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
    Canvas c = new Canvas(bmpGrayscale);
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    ColorMatrix cm = new ColorMatrix();
    cm.setSaturation(0);
    ColorMatrixColorFilter f = new ColorMatrixColorFilter(cm);
    paint.setColorFilter(f);
    c.drawBitmap(bmpOriginal, 0, 0, paint);
    return bmpGrayscale;
}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean you need a threshold algorithm? See the article in [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thresholding_(image_processing)).

Comment: Yes, I need to threshold the grayscale image. Do you know any codes that I could use?

Comment: I would use [otsu's method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Otsu%27s_Method) to choose the best threshold. There is also an optimization where you split the picture into 4 parts until the quality of the threshold for each part is high enough.

Comment: I used this code:
    Imgproc.threshold(imgToProcess, imgToProcess , 2000, 255,      Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY);
But the result only showed a black page. What happened?

Comment: I am a newbie to coding. So could you possibly help me code? I understand what this method does, but I am unsure as to how to apply it. Using otsu's method with my grayscale image would to perfect. Thanks! I really need help with the codes

Comment: There are enough examples around the internet. For instance [this](http://www.labbookpages.co.uk/software/imgProc/otsuThreshold.html) should do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have done some image filtering in the past with android, for the ThresholdingFilter i used this code:

```
public class ThresholdingFilter {

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  METHODS  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    /**
     * Methods that apply a Thresholding Effect on image
     * 
     * @param imageIn the input image
     * @param threshold Integer - value (0-255)  prefered value (threshold = 125)
     * @return
     */ 

    public static AndroidImage process(AndroidImage imageIn, int threshold) {

        // The Resulting image
        AndroidImage imageOut;

        // Initiate the Output image
        imageOut = new AndroidImage(imageIn.getImage());

        // Do Threshold process
        for(int y=0; y<imageIn.getHeight(); y++){
            for(int x=0; x<imageIn.getWidth(); x++){

                if(imageOut.getRComponent(x,y) < threshold){
                    imageOut.setPixelColor(x, y, 0,0,0);
                }
                else{
                    imageOut.setPixelColor(x, y, 255,255,255);
                }               
            }
        }   

        // Return final image
        return imageOut;
    }

}
```

AndroidImage is a Custom Wrapper class for the Android Bitmap

```
public class AndroidImage {

     //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  ATTRIBUTES  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

    // Original bitmap image
    private Bitmap image;

    // Format of the image (jpg/png)
    private String formatName;

    /** Dimensions of image */

    // Width of the image
    private int width;

    // Height of the image
    private int height;

    // RGB Array Color
    protected int[] colorArray;

    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  METHODS  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  

    /**
     * Constructor
     * 
     * @param img the Bitmap from which we create our AndroidImage Object 
     */

    public AndroidImage(Bitmap img){        
        this.image =  img;
        this.formatName = "jpg";
        this.width = img.getWidth();
        this.height = img.getHeight();
        updateColorArray();
    }


    /**
     * Method to reset the image to a solid color
     * 
     * @param color - color to reset the entire image to
     */

    public void clearImage(int color){
        for(int y=0; y<height; y++){
            for(int x=0; x<width; x++){
                image.setPixel(x, y, color);
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method to set color array for image - called on initialization by constructor
     * 
     * 
     */

    private void updateColorArray(){
        colorArray = new int[width * height];
        image.getPixels(colorArray, 0, width, 0, 0, width, height);
        int r, g, b;
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++){
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++){
                int index = y * width + x;
                r = (colorArray[index] >> 16) & 0xff;
                g = (colorArray[index] >> 8) & 0xff;
                b = colorArray[index] & 0xff;
                colorArray[index] = 0xff000000 | (r << 16) | (g << 8) | b;
            }
        }
    }


    /**
     * Method to set the color of a specific pixel
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param color
     */

    public void setPixelColor(int x, int y, int color){
        colorArray[((y*image.getWidth()+x))] = color;
        image.setPixel(x, y, color);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the color of a specified pixel
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return color
     */

    public int getPixelColor(int x, int y){
        return colorArray[y*width+x];
    }

    /**
     * Method to set the color of a specified pixel from an RGB combination
     * 
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @param c0
     * @param c1
     * @param c2
     */

    public void setPixelColor(int x, int y, int c0, int c1, int c2){
        colorArray[((y*image.getWidth()+x))] = (255 << 24) + (c0 << 16) + (c1 << 8) + c2;
        image.setPixel(x, y, colorArray[((y*image.getWidth()+x))]);
    }

    /**
     * Method to get the RED color of a specified pixel 
     *  
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return color of R component
     */

    public int getRComponent(int x, int y){
        return (getColorArray()[((y*width+x))]& 0x00FF0000) >>> 16;
    }


    /**
     * Method to get the GREEN color of a specified pixel
     *  
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return color of G component
     */

    public int getGComponent(int x, int y){
        return (getColorArray()[((y*width+x))]& 0x0000FF00) >>> 8;
    }


    /**
     * Method to get the BLUE color of a specified pixel
     *  
     * @param x
     * @param y
     * @return color of B component
     */

    public int getBComponent(int x, int y){
        return (getColorArray()[((y*width+x))] & 0x000000FF);
    }



    /**
     * Method to rotate an image by the specified number of degrees
     * 
     * @param rotateDegrees
     */

    public void rotate (int rotateDegrees){
        Matrix mtx = new Matrix();
        mtx.postRotate(rotateDegrees);
        image = Bitmap.createBitmap(image, 0, 0, width, height, mtx, true);
        width = image.getWidth();
        height = image.getHeight();
        updateColorArray();
    }

     // Setters and Getters

    /**
     * @return the image
     */

    public Bitmap getImage() {
        return image;
    }

    /**
     * @param image the image to set
     */

    public void setImage(Bitmap image) {
        this.image = image;
    }

    /**
     * @return the formatName
     */

    public String getFormatName() {
        return formatName;
    }

    /**
     * @param formatName the formatName to set
     */

    public void setFormatName(String formatName) {
        this.formatName = formatName;
    }


    /**
     * @return the width
     */

    public int getWidth() {
        return width;
    }

    /**
     * @param width the width to set
     */

    public void setWidth(int width) {
        this.width = width;
    }

    /**
     * @return the height
     */

    public int getHeight() {
        return height;
    }

    /**
     * @param height the height to set
     */

    public void setHeight(int height) {
        this.height = height;
    }

    /**
     * @return the colorArray
     */

    public int[] getColorArray() {
        return colorArray;
    }

    /**
     * @param colorArray the colorArray to set
     */

    public void setColorArray(int[] colorArray) {
        this.colorArray = colorArray;
    }

}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: I put the first code in my binary.java and for the second one, I made a new class and inserted it. But I keep getting an error for AndroidImage. What should I do?

Comment: @Young-HunKim what error did you get, use the two classes as separate class and call them on you activity. use an AsynchronouTask to do filterin because it's a long operation!! and let me know if you get problems

Comment: Right now, I'm using Imgproc.threshold(imgToProcess, imgToProcess, 100, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY); in my binary.java but I feel that it is severely limiting me in what I can do. I noticed that your code had much more functions. It would be great if you could go through my code. Thanks.

Comment: How do I call both the AndroidImage.java and ThresholdingFilter.java on my binary.java? I'm sorry I'm asking so many questions. I need this done by Monday. Thanks

Comment: Also how exactly do you use the two .java files?

Comment: The android app I'm trying to make is to take a picture of a leaf or upload from album and determine whether it is invasive or native. We are using 7 different species and we collected many samples and got many measurements. We plan on putting the measurements into the phone for each leaf. So when a picture is taken on the phone, it will be turned into binary and, like my other question says and find the 4 pixels of the binary, measurements of that leaf will be done and it's measurement will be compared to the table of measurements. Then the name of the leaf will be seen with a %.